# Sending image (.jpg) byte data to an iOS device from a .NET web service, then on the iOS device, encoding it to its respective file type (.jpg)

Tags: c#, ios, web-services, encoding, asmx

I have a web service that sends image byte data (`.jpg`) to an iOS device.  The iOS device saves that data to the `.jpg` that it is, and once it's saved to the local file system, the file cannot be opened due to a "corrupt file" message we get when trying to open it on the iOS device.  The specifics of this message are irrelevant.

I am a .NET developer developing the web service.  I don't know anything about Objective C - we have another developer handling that.

**QUESTION**: What I need to know is if the iOS device expects the byte data to be encoded a certain way, whether it has to be a Base64 string, etc.  I'm not sure what the convention is for sending a file via byte data over to an iOS device.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A downvote, really?  What part of the question qualified for a downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been there, but on the iOS end.
What we did to solve this problem was to have the .NET server send the image as a base64 encoded string, just as you said.

In the iOS end, the dev must then use a base64 decoding class (there are plenty on the internet, this one for example: http://www.imthi.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/base64.zip), transform that into NSData and then create the image with that data.

Should look something like this:

```
NSString *b64string = @"string to decode";
NSData *imgData = [DecoderClass decodeBase64FromString:b64String];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

If the data is correct, it should work.
UIImage is a high-level class and should handle image types (jpg, png, etc) automatically, as long as the data is consistent.

Comment: Awesome info, I'll pass this on to the iOS developer.  Thanks a bunch!